# Getting Public / Private Keys from Firebase Auth

Tags: python, ios, swift, firebase-authentication, rsa

Is there anywhere in Firebase Auth where you can access public and private RSA keys for users? This would be really helpful for my project instead of having to generate some and store them securely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built into Firebase Authentication for storing key pairs for the user. You'll typically want to use a secondary data store (like Firebase's Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore) for that and associate the keys with the user's UID.